# get details of card by clicking on that card - vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a cardview. There are multiple cards. I want details of a card while clicking on that particular card. How can i do that i am not sure?

```
<div class="container">
  <vu-page-card
    v-for="page in pageList"
    :key="page.id"
    :pageId="page.pageId"
    :pageItem="page.pageItem"
    :pageType="page.type"
    class="item"
    @onHomeRefresh="onHomeRefresh"
  />
</div>
```

How to modify or add code to get this functionality? Any simple example is also applicable

Comment: add `@click="some_function"` ? Or emit an event from the component and listen to it? https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact use case. But with what I can see from the code you've given, you could simply attach a click handler to the component and pass the card details as params.

```
<div class="container">
  <vu-page-card
    v-for="page in pageList"
    :key="page.id"
    :pageId="page.pageId"
    :pageItem="page.pageItem"
    :pageType="page.type"
    class="item"
    @click="onCardClick(page)" 
    @onHomeRefresh="onHomeRefresh"
  />
</div>
```